# Android Studio - Could not initialize class java.net.DefaultDatagramSocketImplFactory

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Android Studio builds are failing and the only message in 'Build Output' is `Could not initialize class java.net.DefaultDatagramSocketImplFactory`

Deleting the `C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle` folder and restarting Android Studio fixes the issue temporarily until I restart Studio again.

This has been happening in at least 2 projects (both of which do use `DatagramSocket`) and seem to have started with a recent update. I'm losing my sanity, please help or at least let me know I'm not the only one with this issue.

Here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
#Wed Nov 11 19:44:02 PKT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Top-level `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module-level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.gamepad"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I'm still haunted by this JBTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete cache studio. File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart and check u dependecies. If it`s not work -> u can try **lower** version of gradle

Comment: 'Invalidate Cache/Restart' works but I have to do it every time I start Android Studio. It's way faster than deleting `.gradle` each time so I guess I'll keep doing this until it gets fixed or reinstall. Thanks!

Comment: I'll wait a day for more answers then mark this as accepted if none show up.